# 502 Bad Gateway on editing or creating only for one content type

Tags: nodes

Drupal 9 project. I can create and edit all content types but one. I get a 502 Bad Gateway from Nginx. Theese are the logs:

```
2022-05-05 10:39:11 Error   ***.**.***.***  503 GET /node/6095/edit?destination=/admin/content HTTP/1.0 https://dev.mywebsite.com/admin/content Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.54 Safari/537.36 20.8 K  Acceso SSL/TLS a Apache
2022-05-05 10:39:14 Error   ***.**.***.***      AH01068: Got bogus version 100, referer: https://dev.mywebsite.com/admin/content                Error de Apache
2022-05-05 10:39:14 Error   ***.**.***.***      (22)Invalid argument: AH01075: Error dispatching request to :, referer: https://dev.mywebsite.com/admin/content             Error de Apache
2022-05-05 10:39:14 Error   ***.**.***.***      11051#0: *1230277 upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a [well-understood, standard](https://ma.ttias.be/nginx-proxy-upstream-sent-big-header-reading-response-header-upstream/) NGinx as proxy occurrence.